# Zend Framework 2 and source code repository

Tags: php, build, repository, zend-framework2

We created a ZF2 project with skeleton app and it works fine for a simple test application. Now we are working on a real project. My question is what we should store in the repository (SVN), the whole project structure or just the new source code? ZF2 comes with a vendor directory which is almost 31MB in size (which has the ZF libraries). Should we store the whole vendor folder in SVN?

This is the first time we are using PHP and ZF so are not clear in how we will deliver the complete project to production from SVN. Also what is the build process if at all exists. Any clues/links to "ZF2 project packaging" is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, don't include dependencies in your repository! Putting your dependencies under version control doesn't do any good, it just blows up your repo for no reason.

You want to add the skeleton to your repository and your own library but definitely not the framework or any other dependencies.

The way to go is to use [composer](http://getcomposer.org/) for dependency installation and some kind of build tool like [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) to automate installation of your project.

See the relevant chapter on phptherightway for more information on [how to build your application](http://www.phptherightway.com/#building_your_application).

The most simple build process doesn't even need a build tool

- checkout your project from SVN/git
- run `php composer.phar install` to install the needed dependencies (defined in your composer.json)

But most probably you want to do some more stuff like setup up the environment, deleting some files, etc.

A word about ZF packages. They're not available from packagist but you can install them with composer anyways. You just have to add the dedicated repository to your composer.json as described here: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/composer